# Does Microsoft Azure blob storage allow BitTorrent uploads?

Tags: azure, bittorrent, protocols, blob-storage

Amazon S3 buckets can be uploaded (and downloaded) using the BitTorrent protocol. Can this be done with Azure blob  storage?

I can't find an answer for this on google. Alot of hits are for the Azure bittorrent client and not Azure the cloud host.

Comment: nothing prevents you from running bittorrent clients in Azure. Actually, Microsoft would love that. Lots of money on network traffic.

Comment: While true, @BrunoFaria, I suspect OP wants something more hands-off like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone give me a straight yes or not answer?

Yes, of course. You could create a Azure VM(Iaas) and install bittorrent service on it. It is same as your local PC.

But on Azure VM, you need port bittorrent port on [Azure NSG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg)(Inbound rules).

Comment: I think OP is looking for something like [Amazon S3's built-in torrent tracker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html).